# Homebrew only installs packages without gui?

Tags: homebrew

I'm a newbie from windows entering the linux world.I just bought a mac. Homebrew seems the best package manager for os x, so I have it installed.

Is homebrew only for installation of packages without gui? why not make it capable of installing softwares with gui?

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew proper does not generally install GUI apps. However, there are plugins like [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) that will do what you want. The reason why GUI apps are left up to plugins is to keep the tool focused on its original goal, which is to download and compile source code, rather than to just install binaries. Homebrew is powerful, but it takes a little getting used to. Good luck!